# Template not found: $PRIMARY_SITE_URL/$PRIMARY_SITE_URL/blog/this-is-my-blog

Tags: error-templates, 404-page

Very new to craft CMS, recently just installed XAMPP with php 7 and craft 3 and followed the [getting started tutorial](https://craftcms.com/docs/getting-started-tutorial/) from Craft CMS. Then when I try to preview or open the page created from the tutorial, it gives me a 404 template not found error.

The error is as follows:

```
yii\web\NotFoundHttpException: Template not found: $PRIMARY_SITE_URL/$PRIMARY_SITE_URL/blog/this-is-my-blog in C:\xampp\htdocs\craft\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\controllers\TemplatesController.php:92
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: craft\controllers\TemplatesController->actionRender('$PRIMARY_SITE_U...', Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\craft\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\craft\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(181): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\craft\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Controller.php(190): yii\base\Controller->runAction('render', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\craft\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(534): craft\web\Controller->runAction('render', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\craft\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Application.php(274): yii\base\Module->runAction('templates/rende...', Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\craft\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(104): craft\web\Application->runAction('templates/rende...', Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\craft\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Application.php(259): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\craft\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(392): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\craft\web\index.php(23): yii\base\Application->run()
#10 {main}
```

and it looks like this:
[image]

I have followed all the instructions in the tutorial, and have created the _entry.twig in my templates/blog folder. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Do you have a `PRIMARY_SITE_URL` key in your `.env` file? For example, your .env file might have `PRIMARY_SITE_URL="http://example.test"`

Comment: @ajamesm
No, it doesn't seem like I have it in my .env file. How do I add this in if I am running on localhost at the moment? would it just be `PRIMARY_SITE_URL=localhost`?

Comment: OH WAIT, i put PRIMARY_SITE_URL="http://localhost/craft/web/" and it worked! Thank you so much. I couldn't find any documentations on PRIMARY_SITE_URL, where was I supposed to add this key in?

Answer (score 2):

You have to go to your **Admin Dashboard** > **Settings** > **Sites** > **Your site** and delete *Base URL* field, then save it and try to navigate.

[image]